# MongoDB & Mongoose - with or without schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to `NodeJS` & `MongoDB`. As per my understanding, MongoDB is a NoSQL database which works on the concept of no schema. We don't need to define any schema in MongoDB. Then i came across with a new term i.e. `Mongoose` which allows us to define schema or model structure.

Now it's getting confusing for me. At one end, NoSQL says that we don't need to define any schema and at the another end, Mongoose allows us define schema. Also we know that Mongoose is built on top of `MongoDB`.

Can someone please clarify it, because both statements are `contradict` to each other. ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's not a contradiction but an enhancement. MongoDB has no schema. Mongoose is software to enforce a schema and structure. So rather than store a schema and rules in the database, you define it in software instead.

Comment: Agreed. But if i have to define schema, then i'll prefer to use SQL database, rather than NoSQL. So, isn't it a contradiction ?

Comment: Who said you "have to" define anything. Mongoose can work totally schemaless as well and it also need not be anything other than type conversions that get done for you without the need to do them manually yourself. You can always also just use a raw driver  as no-one said you "have to" use mongoose even. But in reality, typically with a SQL database you still have application logic that defines the class structure even though there is a physical definition stored in the database itself. So a schemaless database is really just removing that redundancy.